# sprintf vs strcat for appending string

Tags: c

I have the following line:

```
  sprintf(someString,"%s%s",someString,someOtherString);
```

The compiler is giving me the following warning:

```
//someFile.c:277:15: error: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3 [-Werror=restrict]
```

I want to replace the line with something that won't give me a compile error. I googled the error and learned about restricted pointers and this was my solution:

```
strcat(someString, someOtherString);
```

Does this provide the same functionality? It does in my testing, but I don't want to break the code's functionality with some edge case.

Comment: @4386427 Does it matter which compiler?

Comment: FYI, there have been debates spanning decades whether sprintf(somestring, "%s...", somestring, ...) is well-defined or not.

Comment: @Joshua Are there?  The man page spells it out as being undefined.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons which man page?

Comment: @4386427 `PRINTF(3)` in linux spells it out.  I originally had an answer that quoted that section but I deleted it since it seemed more tangental than directly answering the question.  Anyways, you can also read it in the C11 standard. 7.21.6.6 p2

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: I've read documentation from old compilers that I can't immediately find claiming an exception for the format string starting with "%s". Apparently early Windows compiler authors believed differently.

Comment: @4386427 In describing the behavior of the `sprintf` function, it states *If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @4386427 Sorry, the section I was quoting above was from the C standard, not the man page.  I figured I'd go straight to the official source of the language rather than one implementation which is allowed some variance in implementation-defined behavior.  From the aforementioned section 7.21.6.6.

Comment: @4386427 gcc rightly complains. Restrict means that the same object cannot be accessed through another pointer. Having destination restricted is sufficient here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sprintf` to print into the same string as one of the sources is undefined behavior.  You could `sprintf` to print into a third string but `strcat` will be more performant anyway as it doesn't have to parse the format string and do the extra copy.  In both cases, it is up to you to ensure that there is sufficient space in `someString` to fit contents of `someOtherString`.

Comment: @GovindParmar I'm not sure I'd expect any special rules in a compiler to deal with it since using `sprintf` in that manner results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yup, just looked at your deleted post with the man page.

Comment: The problem is not just performance, using `sprintf` this way has undefined behavior.

Comment: I'd like to put in a plug for using `strncat` instead, as a perhaps more explicit, more compact way to deal with avoiding writing past the end of `someString`

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the undefined behavior of sprintf as used by op.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `strcat` with a sufficiently large destination array.

Using `sprintf` with the same array as destination and a string argument for `%s` has undefined behavior. Most existing implementations will produce the expected result for the specific case in the question, but the C Standard make it explicitly undefined.

The compiler rightfully complains with a warning that may be hard to decipher:

`passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3`

This means that argument 3 overlaps with the array pointed to by argument 1, which is incorrect if the array pointed to by argument 3 is dereferenced because it would alias memory dereferenced through argument 1 which is declared as a `restrict` pointer in `sprintf` prototype, implying that no other pointer should read or write memory that is accessed through it.

A corner case such as `sprintf(someString, "%.0s%s", someString, someOtherString);` has defined behavior if `someOtherString` fits in `someString` because argument 3 is not dereferenced but the compiler might still issue the warning.

Comment: Not potentially but is incorrect always if dereferenced

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: you are correct. I rephrased the answer.